# How to clear/remove/list the AKMIDISampler sound files added to it?

Tags: audiokit

There is not a visible interface to me that can help with these things. As far as i know, each sound file can play in different notes, so how do i know which sound is where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have any way to that in AudioKit yet, though I think it would be a good feature to add.

Comment: thanks Aurelius, will open the issue on the github page.